# Rails 4: Is there a first_or_initialize for a has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Purchase` that `has_one :shipping_address`.

In one of my methods I have this:

```
@shipping_address ||= purchase.build_shipping_address(
  first_name: shipping_address_first_name,
  ...
)
```

However, I would like to just grab the existing shipping_address attached to the purchase if it exists instead of always creating a new replacement (which I believe deletes the old one and creates a new one in the database).

Is there a way to do `purchase.first_or_build_shipping_address(...)` in Rails?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

@shipping_address ||= purchase.shipping_address || purchase.build_shipping_address

As long as the first one returns nil you will be creating a new one.

Comment: I don't think there's a method for an instance like that: `p.find_by(field: 'shipping_address')` --> undefined method `find_by' for #<Purchase:0x007ff85a2e8948>

Comment: Missed the association, sorry.

Comment: As long as you need to initialize the first of the array you need to use where to return the association in array.

Comment: It is a `has_one`, so there is no array. It fails again: p.shipping_address.where(field: 'relation').first_or_initialize --> undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass

Comment: also field: 'relation' should be replaced by the foreign_key association.
where(purchase_id: 1)